# How can I execute my assembly (a method) on application load in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application (ASP.NET MVC) i deploy in several customers settings. I have a requirement that a particular file needs to be available on disk before my application can start.

I am trying to make a new class library file (assembly) to drop in the bin folder, and the only thing this class library does is to check for that file on disk. It throws an exception or something (havent figured this out yet).

Is there any way of getting my assembly to execute when the application starts / is loaded? So that if that file does not exist on disk It would halt the execution and redirect to a generic error page or something?

This way i can simply drop this assembly in the bin folder.

Comment: Why don't you just add this check to your web application and call it on Application_Start? Why do you want to just drop it in the bin?

Comment: Call your method in Application_Start (in global.asax.cs). But the class library idea is still a sensible one if you want to use this functionality in other apps.